# Properly discontinuous action on homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite group with a properly discontinuous action on $X$. How can I show that $\Gamma$ acts on $H_k(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}$? It's not clear to me why I need to take rational coefficients.

Comment: Most of the assumptions here are unnecessary. A group action gives you a bunch of maps $X \to X$, and those induce maps on homology (on the chain level, even) with any coefficients you like.

Comment: But the functoriality doesn't require that the maps are continuous?

Comment: You have misunderstood, I think, what "properly discontinuous" means. The individual maps $x \mapsto gx$ are still continuous. Indeed, the definition of a group action on a space is a continuous map $G \times X \to X$ such that (list of properties). Properly discontinuous is a technical term used so that you can quotient out by such an action and get a decent space as the result. (It's also redundant in the case of finite groups: every finite group action is properly discontinuous.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a topological group $G$ acts on a space $X$. (This means that the group action $G \times X \to X$ is continuous.) Call "multiplication by $g$" (that is, the map $x \mapsto gx$) $L_g$. Then one has an action on homology with whatever coefficients you want, in particular on $H_k(X;\Bbb Z)$, given by $x \mapsto L_g(x)$, using functoriality of homology. This is a perfectly fine group action. It exists on the chain level; if you have a chain $\sigma: \Delta^k \to X$, it's just $g\sigma := L_g \sigma$.

There's no need for assumption on 1) finiteness 2) properly discontinuous, or 3) the coefficient group. You get an action on homology out of any group action whatsoever.